# unable to open pdf in webview android app

Tags: xml, pdf, webview, android-studio-3.0

Thanks for help in advance. i am making an android app which is basically a **webview based app**. In this app, Everything is working fine but one thing that isn't working is, **PDF files which are present on the website are not opening**. I don't know why? Please help me to solve this problem.

Link to my Source Code:-
http://www.mediafire.com/file/zaab9i3pgx9cg3e/RefereshTest.zip

ScreenShots:

***-Activity_Main XML***

[image: Activity_Main XML]

***Android Manifest XML***

[image: Android Manifest XML]

***Main_Activity Java***

[image: Main_Activity Java]

***App ScreenShot***

[image: App ScreenShot]

Thanks in advance. Please help me.

Link to the Video :- 
http://www.mediafire.com/file/qnr3kxe0bbrhdk1/compressed.mp4

Comment: Hello, Can you please replace the 3 firsts screenshots by copy-paste of your code ? Its easier to edit code as text. Also I cannot really understand the app screenshot. What should we see on it ? Thank you and welcolme to StackOverflow ;) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same problem and solved it : you have to override onStartDownload method in the web view .

There are to methods :

***Force download and open it :***

```
 webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String aUrl, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

            fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(aUrl, contentDisposition, mimetype); //returns a string of the name of the file THE IMPORTANT PART

                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(aUrl));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(aUrl);
                    request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
                    request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));





        }


    });
```

and don't forget to add those methods to open pdf after download :

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            openFile(fileName);        }
    };

    protected void openFile(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + File.separator +
                fileName);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        try {
            this.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
```

Also don't forget declaring perrmission in the :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or you can only

***open it in intent***  :

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Both solutions are tested and works .

Comment: Thanks for the help. This worked for me. You solved my really big issue. Again, thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: @Abhishek so why didn't you accept it as an answer and upvoted it !

Comment: I did but this notification appear whenever I upvote ("Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.")